# Unable to read from '/sys/class/leds/wled:backlight/max_current'

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, logging, sony-xperia, sony-xperia-z

I updated my Sony Z1 Compact to 5.0. And now every 50ms I see message in LogCat

```
Unable to read from '/sys/class/leds/wled:backlight/max_current'
```

What's the problem? And how can i resolve it?

Comment: Well, logcat does contain a lot of warnings and other verbose messages that are perfectly normal.

Comment: But this message every 50 ms. Spaming non-stop. So annoying =/

Comment: You can filter log :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30154331/xperia-z1-compact-android-lollipop-unable-to-read-from-sys-class-leds-wledbac

hope this could help.